# What is the term to refer to a person who can see the same subject from many points of view?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

What is the term to refer to a person who can see the same subject from many points of view, and that these coexist?

¿Cuál es el término para referirse a una persona que puede ver un mismo tema desde muchos puntos de vista, y que estos coexistan?

Answer (score 1):

Sería un [ecléctico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclecticismo). Hay más palabras que son parecidas pero no son tan buenas porque no se ajustan exactamente a tu definición o tienen connotaciones peyorativas (*tibio*, *indiferente*, *imparcial*, *neutral*, *ecuánime*, *etc*).

Answer (score 0):

**Persona Empática**

Creo que el término para referirse a la facultad de una persona que posee la capacidad de ver un mismo tema desde varios puntos de vista, y a la vez entender estas distintas disposiciones e intereses dispares, se llama "** Capacidad Empática**" y si es referida a la persona que posee esas capacidades, la denominamos "**Persona Empática**".

El término "**Empatía**" en psicología es más amplio que el que podemos encontrar en la RAE, y así se refiere al concepto de **empatía** como la capacidad de comprender y compartir sentimientos, emociones o puntos de vista que responden a los diversos intereses que puedan tener diversas personas sobre una o varias cosas. En definitiva, la **empatía** nos permite ver las cosas desde la perspectiva de otra u otras personas a la vez, y no solo la nuestra.

Las **personas empáticas** pueden ver un mismo tema desde varios ángulos o posiciones, y entender cada uno de ellos, por lo que estas personas son escasas y muy solicitadas en multitud de campos, ya que la **persona empática** puede llegar acuerdos o dar con soluciones entre las partes discordantes o intervinientes para que estas puedan quedar lo más satisfechas posible.